# Who sends 'zxing.org' user agent

Tags: zxing, user-agent

I've seen the 'zxing.org' user agent a couple of times. Well I'm aware that QR Barcode Readers which donot change ZXing basic user agent identify themselves as 'ZXing (Android)' so I'm wondering what this one could be. Has someone got any clue about it ?

Thank you,
Thibault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the online version of ZXing under http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx which results in a request with the user-agent “zxing.org”. (I've tested it with a example bar code image and made a lookup in the access.log.)